# An attribute for all checkbox in page is changing each time I run the code, how to find element for checkbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Refer this firepath :

```
.//*[@id='gwt-uid-20138']
```

HTML :

```
<input id="gwt-uid-20138" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0">
```

Note: this id value gets changed.

Comment: Which Selenium Client are you using? Java/Python/C# ?

Comment: Please give more HTML code, as below tomasz.myszka answered, you have to use the text before/behind the checkbox to assist to find the checkbox. I don't think you can not  use id startswith 'gwt-uid' to find the checkbox, i guess there are may elements which id startswith 'gwt-uid'

Answer (score 1):

If id is changing, maybe try to find checkbox using label next to this checkbox?
Try something like this:

```
/label[text()="test"]/preceding-sibling::input
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the `checkbox` element you have to take help of the `id` attribute. But as you can see the `id` attribute is dynamic, so we have to make our `Locator Strategy` **dynamic**. Now if you observe the `id` attribute closely you will observe that the **gwt-uid-** part is `constant` and only the remaining part i.e. **20138** is `dynamic`. So we can use the **starts-with()** method for the `dynamic` **`id`** and to identify the **checkbox** uniquely we will also include the **type** attribute while constructing the locator. So to find the `checkbox` element you can use the following line of code :

- Java :

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-') and @type='checkbox']"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If selector of your checkbox keeps on changing you need to identify it with the property which is always constant and unique.

From your example you can see that `gwt-uid-` part is always constant, you can use the same to identify the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'gwt-uid-')]"));
```